# Creating a multiplechoice field using many to many relationship

Tags: django

Im trying to add a field called, interested_fields inside my personalInfo model which users can choose from and the choices themselves come from another models' objects with the help of ManyToMany relation between the two models. Here are my models.py codes(I simplified my personal model by removing some other fields like name, age, etc in order to make it more readable for you):

```
class Field(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='default')
    title = CharField(max_length=32)


class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    interested_fields = models.ManyToManyField(Field, blank=True)
```

then, I created a ModelForm like this:

```
class InterestedFieldsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    interested_fields = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=Field.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInfo
        fields = ['interested_fields']
```

and created a get and post functions inside my views like this:

```
class PersonalView(View):
    template_name = 'reg/personal.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        context['fields'] = Field.objects.all()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InterestedFieldsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = request.user
                profile.save()
        else:
            form = InterestedFieldsForm()

        return render(request, 'reg/done.html', context={'form': form})
```

and finally in template, inside the form I added this for loop:

```
{% for field in fields %}
                                <label class="containerq ant-col ant-col-md-6 ant-col-xs-8" >
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="interested_fields" {% if field.slug in user.personalInfo.interested_fields %} checked="checked" {% endif %} value="{{field.title}}">
                                        <span style="margin-left:7px" class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>{{field.title}}</span>
                                </label>
                            {% endfor %}
```

when I submit the form it gives me this error:
cannot unpack non-iterable Field object
Im new to django so I really dont know what am I doing wrong. thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

```
interested_fields = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Field.objects.all(), required=False).
```

Comment: the error is gone! but when I check some of the choices and submit the form, it wont get saved. but no errors

Comment: Check if the form is valid

Comment: yes it is valid

Comment: I think you also need to call `profile.save_m2m()` after `profile.save()`.

Comment: it gives me this error: 'PersonalInfo' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Comment: `form.save_m2m()`, sorry my bad.

Comment: its working, but it wont update the previous. it creates a new personal info

Comment: `form = InterestedFieldsForm(request.POST, instance=PersonalInfo.objects.get(user=user))`. You need to pass the form an instance variable so it updates the object instead of creating another one.

Comment: ok that got fixed but when I want to add a new user and fill the form by that user, it gives me this: PersonalInfo matching query does not exist.

Comment: Then make sure it exists first and if not create it. This is beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: when I remove instance=PersonalInfo.objects.get(user=user) and submit the form and come back and put it back everything works. what is causing this?